# Quero pegar a linha que tenha a maior nota do Enem em um Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Quero saber como pegar a linha com a maior nota dentro de um DataFrame com as notas do Enem.

Eu usei a função **.max()** na coluna que eu queria, mas ela só retorna o valor daquela coluna e eu quero mostrar todas as informações da linha em que aquele valor se encontra!

Answer (score 3):

Use o [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) com o [idxmax()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

Veja abaixo:

### Criando dataframe teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_A": ["a", "b", "c"], "col_B": [1, 3, 2]})

df
  col_A  col_B
0     a      1
1     b      3
2     c      2
```

### Recuperando a linha com o maior (max) número na coluna B (col_B)

```
df.loc[df["col_B"].idxmax()]

col_A    b
col_B    3
Name: 1, dtype: object
```